# Play with NSDictionary in console in Xcode

Tags: objective-c

New to Xcode and obj-c.

Is it possible to sort through data structures in the console like you with JavaScript?

```
-(void)fetchInfo
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someurl"];
    NSData *jsonResults = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonResults
                                                             options:0
                                                               error:NULL];
   NSLog(@"CitiBike Results = %@", dictionary);

}
```

The results are logged, but I now want to play with the returned dictionary

Answer (score 4):

If you make a mutable copy, you can fiddle with that in the console

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [dictionary mutableCopy];
```

then

```
p mutableDictionary[@"key"] = @"Hello, World!"
```

EDIT: you can also store it in a convenience variable in lldb like

```
expr NSMutableDictionary *$md = mutableDictionary
```

so that if it goes out of scope, as long as it's alive, you can still access it in the debugger like

```
p $md[@"key"] = @"Convenience!"
```

Comment: I think I'm missing something. I can log the mutable dictionary but when I call p md[@"key"] after the build succeeds nothing is returned.

Comment: well if you call `p md[@"key"] = @"test"` then nothing will be returned. But afterward if you call `po md` or `po md[@"key"]` you'll see the newly added pair.